# How to move or slide an image in VSE

Tags: image, video-sequence-editor, video

I would like to know if there is a way to make an image move or slide to another point using the video editor.

Comment: Do you mean movement within the frame (like left to right or up and down)? Or do you mean sliding the video strip to a different time so a certain frame plays at a different time?

Comment: yes like within the frame

Answer (score 4):

Select the video strip you want to move, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and look for Effect Srip->Transform.

[image]

Select the newly created transform strip and press <kbd>N</kbd> to revel the control panel.
You can move and rescale the image using **Position** and **Scale**.

[image]

Those values are keyframemable. To add a keyframe hover over the value and press <kbd>I</kbd>